# Convex lens (flat end) with pst-optic

Tags: pstricks, pst-optic

Is it possible to get each end of a convex lens to be flat, like this:

[image]

(I haven't been able to find anything regarding this in the [manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-optic/pst-optic-doc.pdf).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-optic}
\newcommand\Lens[1][]{%
  \psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none](-1,-2.7)(1,2.7)}\rput(0,0){\lensSPH[#1]}\endpsclip}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-3)(1,3)
\Lens[lensType=CVG,lensWidth=1,drawing=false,lensColor=BleuVerre]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect (as usual), Herbert!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a very small value for `lensDepth` in `\lensSPH`; in the following example I used two of these lenses; the one on the left has a rectangle superimposed just to compare it with a real flat figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-optic}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-3)(6,3)
\rput(0,0){\lensSPH[lensType=DVG,lensWidth=0.5,lensDepth=0.00001,AB=1,OA=-5,drawing=false,lensColor=BleuVerre
]}
\pspolygon[fillcolor=lightgray,opacity=0.2,fillstyle=solid,linecolor=blue](-0.25,-3)(0.25,-3)(0.25,3)(-0.25,3)
\rput(2,0){\lensSPH[lensType=DVG,lensWidth=0.5,lensDepth=0.00001,AB=1,OA=-5,drawing=false,lensColor=BleuVerre
]}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: This is not a convex lens but a 'flat' one; only the ends should be flat and the rest of the lens convex (like the one on [this figure](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Lens1.svg/390px-Lens1.svg.png)).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I put the picture into your question, to make it clearer what you mean by "end" `:-)`